# Generic method with unspecified type possible?

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I do need a solution for loading lists of objects - lookups where only one property is referenced from the current object as in this example.

```
class LookupObjectAddress
{
 [...]
 public string City
 { get; set; }
 [...]
}

class WorkingObject
{
 // references the property from LookupObjectAddress
 public string City
 { get; set; }
}
```

For the lookup I need a List to be loaded from the database, to know from where to load the information I use an Attribute

```
class WorkingObject
{
 // references the property from LookupObjectAddress
 [Lookup(Type=typeof(LookupObjectAddress), staticloaderclass="LookupObjLoader", staticloaderMethod="LookupObjLoadMethod")]
 public string City
 { get; set; }
}
```

After reading out the PropertyInfo for the WorkingObject.City Property I know the type of the lookup object, and from which class with which method to load it. 
Now I need the bridge to get a List with that three parameters to work with.

```
Type loaderClass = Type.GetType(classname);
MethodInfo loaderMethod = loaderClass.GetMethod(loadmethod);
object objList = loaderMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] {});
```

Since I need the typed List<> for using properties of the LookupObjects on the UI, how can I become a useable list in Code?

My ideal Outcome would be, if I could just type:

```
var list = Loader.Load(type, "LookupObjLoader", "LookupObjLoadMethod");
```

where the parameters are read from the Attribute.

Comment: I don't really understand your question. Are you saying that loaderMethod.Invoke() should return a List<T> instead?

Comment: Can you write some code that's your ideal outcome?

Comment: That is right, to work properly with the list, I would need to know hardcoded the type the list is of. But I want the UserControl for that to be as generic as possible and not with Cases for each ObjectType I have as Lookup-possible.

Comment: So your question is just: how do I create a generic list when the generic argument is known at runtime?

Comment: The generic argument is known just at runtime, correct. At design time I do not know it, and therefore do not how how to handle this in code.

Comment: Can you, instead of "var" specify what type of data you want returned? Do you want a list of type objects? ie. basically (if the syntax was allowed) List<type> ?

Comment: Note, that either way, Loader.Load would have to return a non-generic list in any case, there is no way you can specify the correct generic list-type for the return value, without knowing the type at compile time. You can, however, generate the correct list type and return it, you just have to store it in a non-generic variable. ie. "IList list = new List<String>(...); return list";

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to produce a `List<T>` type, and thus instance, at runtime, where T comes from a `Type` object (ie. not known at compile-time), you would do this:

```
Type genericListType = typeof(List<>); // yes, this really is legal syntax
Type elementType = ...
Type specificListType = genericListType.MakeGenericType(elementType);
// specificListType now corresponds to List<T> where T is the same type
// as elementType
IList list = (IList)Activator.CreateInstance(specificListType);
```

This will produce, at runtime, the correct list type and store it in the `list` variable.

Note that there is no way you can get the compiler to infer the variable type, so this:

```
var list = Loader.Load(...)
```

will still not produce a `List<T>` **type**, it will have to use a non-generic, known-at-compile-time type to store the list, like `IList`, but the object you store in it can be a generic one, produced the way I describe above.

Comment: This should do. Thanks for it.